# Problem with Angular Compiler on Component Input when using inheriting/extending interfaces

Tags: angular, typescript

I have got a problem with an Input() Variable of an Angular Component. It throws a type related error on the pages template file. I have got two interfaces, one page and one component to make the error occur.

The two interfaces are `Bike` and `BikeMin` where `Bike` extends `BikeMin` (and other interfaces):

```js
export interface Bike extends BikeRemote, BikeMin, BikeLocal {}
```

I have got a Component `BikeFeaturePickerComponent` with an ngModel of type `BikeMin`:

```js
export class BikeFeaturePickerComponent {
  @Output("bikeChange")
  public bikeChange: EventEmitter<BikeMin> = new EventEmitter<BikeMin>();
  @Input("bike")
  public bike: BikeMin;

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  constructor(public featuresService: FeaturesService, public bikeInfoService: BikeInfoService) {}
}
```

I am using the Component `BikeFeaturePickerComponent` on the Page `DetailPage` which has the public property `bike: Bike`.
*detail.page.ts*:

```js
export class DetailPage implements OnInit {
  public bike: Bike;
  ...
}
```

*detail.page.html*:

```html
<app-bike-feature-picker [(bike)]="bike"></app-bike-feature-picker>
```

Now the error occurs on the *detail.page.html*. It says that I cannot assign the variable of type `Bike` to a variable of type `BikeMin` although `Bike` has all the properties of `BikeMin`. Inside of functions I can assign variables of type `Bike` to parameters of type `BikeMin`. But when using Input() from @angular/core I get the following error:
[image]

No errors occur at runtime (`ionic serve`) either. The code can be executed despite the compiler error. Also no errors on `ionic build`. Possibly the error is only caused by Visual Studio code. But how can I get rid of it?

Thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

As you're using two way binding, the casting of the type is going both up and down i.e. `Bike -> BikeMin` and `BikeMin -> Bike`. I'm guessing it's the `BikeMin -> Bike` that's causing the issue

You may need to use a union type in DetailPage

```js
public bike: Bike | BikeMin;
```

Comment: Not quite the solution but your hint got me to it!
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70011876/11063209
It works when changing the Output type to the more general type `Bike`. Because the specific interface `BikeMin` cannot be castet to the generel `Bike` interface on the Output:

```js
  @Output("bikeChange")
  public bikeChange: EventEmitter<Bike> = new EventEmitter<Bike>();
  @Input("bike")
  public bike: BikeMin;
```